# Inner Join return wrong records

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return all the `family_name` records , where the prod_type is `P` .

The tables are :

Table products

[image]

With the records

[image]

And table Family 
[image]

With the records

[image]

But when I execute the query  :

```
SELECT family_name
FROM family
INNER JOIN products
ON products.prod_type="P";
```

I get this :

[image]

Any idea how to fix it ? thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for "P" in your WHERE clause instead, and use family_code as the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT f.family_name
FROM family f
INNER JOIN products p ON p.family_code = f.family_code
WHERE p.prod_type='P';
```

Basically, your initial query was returning the family_name of every row in `family` matched with every row in `products` (with a prod_type of 'P').